# How to update UITableView asynchronously?

Tags: ios, uitableview

If an array that is the data source for a UITableView needs to be updated asynchronously, e.g., its members are deleted and appended by the data continually received over the network, then how can we update the UITableView and insert and remove the corresponding rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the main queue for updating it, so when an async function is called from a networking event it will be redirected to the main thread

```
func theFuncToBeCalledBySyncEvent(addThisCell cell: UITableViewCell){
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       theTable.beginUpdates()
       theSourceArray.append(cell)
       theTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: theSourceArray.count - 1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
       theTable.endUpdate()
   }
}
```

Comment: So you update both the underlying collection and the UI on the main thread.

Comment: Its not guaranteed that a set of cellForRowAt calls doesn't get interrupted by a datasource change though? Even on the same thread?

Comment: If they are in the same thread, they will be executed in the order they were added to the queue.

Comment: so for example, if  the data source sends a deleterow message, while an addrow is yet to be executed, the addrow will be executed first

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one `tableView.reloadData()` will always refresh the entire table view. So if data comes through the network you can always just adjust your dataSource and then call `tableView.reloadData()`.

You can also use `tableView.beginUpdates()` + `tableView.endUpdates()` with corresponding insert, delete, move calls (see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates)) But those are typically used for animating the changes. - You have to update the data source first and know the index paths you're trying to change though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, .reloadData() is good for a small set of data because it refreshes the whole table.
And about beginUpdates()/.endUpdates in case of async what happens if 4 threads simultaneously are calling for changes in the data source?

Comment: well, UI updates should happen on the main thread so you shouldn't have multiple threads making changes to the table view at the same time. Similarly if you call reloadData and your data source changes while that's happening you can very easily get a crash when trying to access the dataSource (since it started reloading the data when there were say 5 elements, but now 1 just deleted so index out of bounds when you get to the 5th) so I'd rethink that approach. Efficiency wise, `reloadData` only triggers a refresh of the visible cells so its not problem to spam that on every update.

Comment: If you really wanted to go the being/endUpdates route you really need to enforce some sort of synchronousness to it (you should not be changing the dataSource at the same time you are doing table updates, that's asking for a crash). You can try making your own serial thread/queue and dispatching changes to the data source and the being/endUpdates there so they happen in order and not a the same time. Also note that the `performBatchUpdates` method seems to be preferred by apple over begin/endUpdates.